# recognizing Drupal from website code

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Can I make impossible for people to recognize I'm using Drupal framework behind my website ?

In other terms, can somebody easily see I'm using Drupal from the generated html code ?

I would to know all the strategies to detect it.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just by looking at the generated source code, it's fairly easy to detect. If you look at the stylesheets included, you'll see they come from a Drupal install. For example :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/mywebsite/modules/node/node.css?e" />
```

The pattern '/modules/node/node.css' is typical. Add to that `<body>` classes like `front logged-in two-sidebars`, and anyone who has already manipulated drupal a little will recognize it... Sorry about that, but I'm pretty sure you can't do anything to mask your using drupal

Comment: Agreed. I'd concentrate on patching your Drupal to latest version to prevent any security risks (if that was OP's primary concern, in the first place).

Comment: ok thanks. I guess it is the same for other CMS, you cannot explicitly read the CMS name, but you can recognize it by analyzing the html code.. ?

Comment: Also, there's the drupal.js file that extends jQuery that is included on every page. That's kind of a dead giveaway.

Comment: If Drupal is set to compress the CSS files, then it will generate a single CSS file, and it's not that easy to understand if a site is using Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make impossible for people to recognize I'm using Drupal framework behind my website?

No, you can't. Despite of the output returned from Drupal for any page (the output is changed if the option to compress CSS, or JavaScript files is selected), there are some files that needs to be accessible from an anonymous user, in order for the site to work; in example, there are some files present in the misc directory that are characteristic of a Drupal installation (or of a CMS derived from Drupal), like misc/drupal.js that is accessible as `http://example.com/misc/drupal.js`.